How to add two rows to get an additional row
I have the following code in R that gives me the proportion of responses that are either 1,2,3 or 4 to different questions labelled "h12a" to "h12h". However, I'm stuck on one small thing for a bit too long and can't figure out how to do this.
I want to add a row to the table which gives me the proportion of responses that are either 1 or 2 i-e I want to add the values of row1 and row2 and put that as an additional row in the table.
I have:



x
h12a




1
0.5


2
0.1


3
0.1


4
0.3



I want:



x
h12a




1
0.5


2
0.1


3
0.1


4
0.3


1_2
0.6



This is my code:
H12<-tibble(x=seq(1:4))
for (i in c(1:8)){
  A=df.e%>%filter(ep==1)%>%
    select(paste0('h12',letters[i]))%>%filter(!is.na(.))%>%
    mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)%>%
    table()%>%prop.table()%>%as.tibble()%>%
    mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)%>%
    setNames(c('x',paste0('h12',letters[i])))
  H12=left_join(H12,A)
}


We can create a custom function and apply it to the dataset.
This function accepts a data.frame, a target question column, and the levels to sum as inputs.
But the best advice we can give is actually to avoiding workflows like this one.
The resulting data.frame is not "tidy", int includes different information for the same column. Column x will then include "the indexes of answers" PLUS a summary.
We'd usually rather have the summaries in separate objects.
h12 <- tibble(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    h12a = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3)
)

add_row_custom <- \(data.frame, column, levels, question) {
    new_row <- data.frame |>
        filter({{column}} %in% levels) |>
        summarise(
            {{column}} := paste(levels, collapse = "_"),
            {{question}} := sum({{question}})
        ) |>
        mutate({{column}} := as.character({{column}}))
    bind_rows(mutate(data.frame, {{column}} := as.character({{column}})), new_row)
}

add_row_custom(h12, x, 1:2, h12a)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  x      h12a
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1       0.5
2 2       0.1
3 3       0.1
4 4       0.3
5 1_2     0.6

Data
h12 <- structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), h12a = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
      x  h12a
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.5
2     2   0.1
3     3   0.1
4     4   0.3

